# Pythonic way to efficient create dictionaries from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, ranking, recommendation-engine

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains columns `id`, `date_created`, `rank_1`, `rank_2`, `rank_3`. Below shows 2 rows of the dataframe.

| id | date_created | rank_1 | rank_2 | rank_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2223 | 3/3/21 3:26 | [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) | [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) | [www.ford.com](http://www.ford.com) |
| 1112 | 2/25/21 1:35 | [www.autoblog.com](http://www.autoblog.com) | [www.motor1.com](http://www.motor1.com) | www.webull.com |

I am trying to assign a new column to this df and call it `rank_dict`, which will assign number 3 to the rank_1 URL, number 2 to rank_2 URL and number 1 to rank_3 URL.
So the ideal result would look like this:

| id | date_created | rank_1 | rank_2 | rank_3 | rank_dict |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2223 | 3/3/21 3:26 | www.google.com | [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) | [www.ford.com](http://www.ford.com) | {www.google.com:3, [www.yahoo.com:2](http://www.yahoo.com:2), [www.ford.com:1}](http://www.ford.com:1%7D) |
| 1112 | 2/25/21 1:35 | www.autoblog.com | www.motor1.com | www.webull.com | {www.autoblog.com:3, [www.motor1.com:2](http://www.motor1.com:2), [www.webull.com:1}](http://www.webull.com:1%7D) |

I know how to do this if it's not a Pandas df. For example, if I have these key values lists:

`keys = ['www.google.com','www.yahoo.com','www.ford.com']`

`values = [3, 2, 1]`

I can do `res_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))` to turn it into the dict: `{'www.google.com': 3, 'www.yahoo.com': 2, 'www.ford.com': 1}`.

But I couldn't figure out an elegant way to perform this dictionary creation in a Pandas df. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is `apply` and use `enumerate` to get the, well, enumeration:

```
df['rank_dict'] = (df.filter(like='rank_')
                     .apply(lambda x: {v:3-k for k,v in enumerate(x)}, axis=1)
                  )
```

Output:

```
     id   date_created             rank_1           rank_2          rank_3                                          rank_dict
0  2223   3/3/21 3:26     www.google.com    www.yahoo.com     www.ford.com  {'www.google.com': 3, 'www.yahoo.com': 2, 'w...'
1  1112  2/25/21 1:35   www.autoblog.com   www.motor1.com   www.webull.com  {'www.autoblog.com': 3, 'www.motor1.com': 2,...'
```